# gulp watch files update jsdoc

Tags: javascript, gulp, jsdoc3

I'm trying to watch some files in a directory and automatically update there documentation with jsdoc. I use gulp to watch the file and run jsdoc see code below.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const watch = require('gulp-watch');
const jsdoc = require('gulp-jsdoc3');

gulp.task('doc', function(cb) {
  const config = require('./jsdoc.json');
  return watch(['../upload/**/*.js'], { ignoreInitial: false })
        .pipe(jsdoc(config, cb));
});
```

When I run this task it doesn't update my jsdoc when a file is changed. Does jsdoc not work together with the watch function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s not sure that the problem comes from gulp-jsdoc3. Maybe you want to split your task into two tasks.

1. task for the job and the
2. for the watcher

   ```
       const gulp = require('gulp');
       const watch = require('gulp-watch');
       const jsdoc = require('gulp-jsdoc3');


       gulp.task('jsdoc-task', function() {

             console.log('task is running')

             const config = require('./jsdoc.json');
             return gulp.src( 'scr/files' )
               .pipe(jsdoc(config)).
               .pipe(gulp.dest( 'your destination path ));

       });


       gulp.task('watch', function() {

         gulp.watch('files-to-watch', [jsdoc-task]);

       });
   ```

Please note there is no `return` for the watcher and also the `files to watch` src should not be the same as the output destination files.

You can now see the `consol.log` and check out if the task was started.

Now it should be easier to find out whats going wrong. If it´s not working check out the error message for more details.

Comment: Thanks it works, but for jsdoc you don't need to specify a gulp.dest(), jsdoc handle it by it self.